# How to count a string in arraylist using c#.net

Tags: c#, string, arraylist, count

I have an arraylist with strings in it which are seperated by ';' in the strings.So my question is that how can I count the 'type' element in it by ID and date in strings

```
   ArrayList arrn=new ArrayList ();
   arrn.Add(item.Key + ";" + datetime.ToString() + ";type1");


"1;2017-5-3 20:36:41;type1"
"1;2017-5-3 20:36:41;type1"
"3;2017-5-3 20:36:41;type2"
"3;2017-5-3 20:36:41;type2"
"2;2017-5-3 20:36:41;type3"
"2;2017-5-3 20:36:41;type3"
"1;2017-5-4 20:36:41;type2"
"1;2017-5-4 20:36:41;type2"
"4;2017-5-3 20:36:41;type1"
"4;2017-5-3 20:36:41;type1"
```

I want the below output

```
1 2017-5-3 : count type1 :2
1 2017-5-4 : count type2 :2
2 2017-5-3 : count type3 :2
3 2017-5-3 : count type2 :2
4 2017-5-3 : count type1 :2
```

How can I do this Please help me

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: First you'll need parsing code to turn those strings into something with separate values (and likely parse to `DateTime`).  Then the Linq would be something like `var results = parsed.GroupBy(p => new { p.Id, p.TimeStamp.Date, p.Type}).Select(g => $"{g.Key.Id} {g.Key.Date} : count {g.Key.Type} : {g.Count()}");`

Comment: dear  juharr :Please Send Me some code

Comment: Seems, you asked [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/1186119/How-to-group-by-arraylist-in-csharp-net#answer1) on CodeProject board.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a

```
IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, IDictionary<string, int>>>
```

structure defined to track the counter.

Split the string on ";" and iterate over the tokens and add them to above structure by testing for existence of the key. If you're adding a key for the first time don't forget to default the value either to the Dictionary<> object or set the counter to 1/0.

Comment: I want you to try the and figure out. It should be very simple like 

foreach(var item in arrn)
{
   var tokens = item.Split(';');
   foreach(var token in tokens)
   {
     // Add your logic here
   }
}

Comment: dear  Gururaj : how can I group by this arraylist according to type and datetime and id

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrn = new ArrayList{
    "1;2017-5-3 20:36:41;type1",
    "1;2017-5-3 20:36:41;type1",
    "3;2017-5-3 20:36:41;type2",
    "3;2017-5-3 20:36:41;type2",
    "2;2017-5-3 20:36:41;type3",
    "2;2017-5-3 20:36:41;type3",
    "1;2017-5-4 20:36:41;type2",
    "1;2017-5-4 20:36:41;type2",
    "4;2017-5-3 20:36:41;type1",
    "4;2017-5-3 20:36:41;type1"};
arrn.ToArray()
    .GroupBy(o => string.Join(" ", ((string) o).Split(';', ' ').Take(2)))
    .Select(objects => $"{objects.Key} : count :{objects.Count()}");
```

If you want a beautiful solution, think yourself. Gururaj pointed out to think about using dictionaries, informing yourself about those should help.
However, the whole attempt with ArrayLists seems quite strange to me - but I can't know wether you get the ArrayList from an API or something like that, so I won't suggest to use another type.

If you have any former specific questions after you did some research and tried some stuff, feel free to ask.